# Wordpress posts editable by guest users without subscription. is this possible?

Tags: wiki, wordpress, collaboration

I'd like all my wordpress posts to be editable by all users, guests included.
does anybody know if this is possible?
I already tried all the "wiki" plugins but without success.

Answer (score 1):

it's absolutely possible. However, there are certain step that require manual programming.
The step is:

1. create an edit page in non admin area
2. do the editing there (you can mimic admin's edit page or you just display the body only)
3. upon saving, you can, either create new user programmatically and assign that user as the editor (this, off course will require another table or another mechanism) or leave the editor as post's previous owner

Comment: I'm sorry @silent this is not totally clear to me. what do yo mean by "create an edit page"? what's an edit page? and what it is a non-admin area?

Comment: edit page is a page where you can edit this particular post. This is custom theme file. non-admin area is, somewhere outside your /wp-admin/